# How do I type a diameter symbol on MathJax-enabled sites?

Tags: support, mathjax

Is there a directive for a diameter symbol ⌀ in MathJax?

The internet mentions `\diameter` but that seems to require some package (*wasysym*? or something) that isn't supported here and so doesn't work.

Right now I just search the internet for the symbol then copy and paste it, but if there's something I can type, I'd rather use that.

---

Inb4 `\phi`: The diameter symbol closely resembles the Greek letter Phi (Φ / φ / ϕ), but it isn't the same, and Phi shouldn't be used for "diameter".

The empty set symbol (∅) also closely resembles the diameter symbol, but isn't the same, either. Empty set is more of a numeric zero than an actual circle.

Comment: I tried http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html as suggested [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/11284#11284) but that doesn't render anything you already found. It might be that there is no better way ... :/

Comment: I'm not sure if it's officially the right symbol, but `\varnothing` looks quite close.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Oh, I should've mentioned that one too. They are also close but technically it's not right. The empty set symbol (`\varnothing`) is [U+2205](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2205), the diameter symbol is [U+2300](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2300). The former is, symbolically, a numeric zero with a slash through it, while the latter is a circle with a diagonal line.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Wait. I didn't realize `\varnothing` and `\emptyset` could be different. I just knee-jerk assumed `\varnothing` was "empty set", but some cursory searching is making me think that was a bad assumption. Hmm, need to look into this more deeply.

Comment: @rene That site is so much fun, haha.

Comment: Yes, `\varnothing` is indeed meant to be a variant empty set symbol, alternative to `\emptyset`. But unlike the latter, it looks like a *circle* (not zero) with a diagonal line, so it is the right shape for the diameter symbol; the only question is if it’s “semantically correct”.

Comment: (FWIW, I seem to have used `\varnothing` for a diameter symbol in my Ph.D. thesis, hence I must have had conluded that it was the optimal choice.)

Comment: Related: *[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It feels like cheating, but there's `\unicode{8960}`. Still, it's exactly the right character. You can make any character this way, by [looking up its decimal number](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2300/index.htm).

Comment: ah well. not ideal. but accurate. good idea thanks.